# How to change background color of ActionBar title?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

No matter how I modify the styles, the background color of the box pointed to by the red arrow just won't change from the background.

[image: img]

How do I change that color? I'm targeting 4.0+ and don't care about 4.0- devices and OSes.

**Here's a link to [my styles.xml file](https://gist.github.com/chakrit/6019757).** Sorry I had to censor a few things as this project is under an NDA.

I have tried many things including:

- Changing `android:background` in `windowTitleBackgroundStyle`
- Changing `android:background` in `actionBarStyle`
- Changing `android:background` in `actionBarWidgetStyle`
- Changing `android:actionBarItemBackground`

None of those work. That text view seems to always stick to the `android:background` value from my base theme and nothing was able to override it.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Use http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator to generate a set of resources, and see what's in there that may be of relevance that you have not yet tried.

Answer (score 4):

Well you need to change android:background with windowBackground

```
<style name="CCCBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/nav_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CCCWidgetActionBar</item>

</style>
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Wow, after 2 years haha. I'm not sure if this is the right solution since I can't test it in the question's context anymore. If someone else comes along and say this works, i'll mark as accepted.

Comment: hehe yesterday I faced this issue I always use custom action bar :S .... I tested it(windowBackground) and it is working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

There is the interisting part of your xml file :

```
<!-- ActionBar -->
    <style name="CCCWidgetActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/nav_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/nav_text</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CCCWidgetActionBarTitle</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/CCCWidgetActionBarTitle</item>

        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CCCWindowTitle</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CCCWindowTitleBackground</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/nav_background</item>
    </style>
```

Just change  :

```
<item name="android:background">@color/nav_background</item>
```

By

```
<item name="android:background">@color/pink</item>
```

Or any color else.

Works fine for me.

Comment: Does not work on my Galaxy S II. Same problem as stated in the question.

Comment: The title text does not use the action bar background, only the application background style. This makes it impossible to change that one particular color without also changing everything else's background color.

Comment: I have same problem too on my Lenovo S880. I suspect maybe this is device problem, however Google+ app has a nice actionbar color on the same device.. strange

Comment: This not only changes the ActionBar Title, but also the whole bg!

Answer (score 1):

you make custom Action-bar and possible to change the Title Background Color, whatever you want.

Follow this Steps:

Only possible for this to make Custom Sherlock bar for Title.

create separate xml file for title on App.

that file contains like this..

In this custom layout, we can able to change the background color using color code..

header_sherlock.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3"
android:background="#008000"
>

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_tvleft"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutpaddingleft"
    android:text="Textview"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
    android:textSize="@dimen/header_leftbtn"
     /> 


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_tvcenter"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/sherlockpaddingright"   
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/sherlockpaddingleft"
    android:text="Textview"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="@dimen/header_title"
     />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_tvright"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutpaddingright"
    android:text="Textview"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="@dimen/header_rightbtn"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

For MainActivity or which activity you want to add title :

```
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.header_sherlock);
    header_tvleft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_tvleft);
    header_tvleft.setText("LeftTitleName");
    header_tvcenter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_tvcenter);
    header_tvcenter.setText("CenterTitleName");
    header_tvright = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_tvright);
    header_tvright.setText("RightTitleName");
```

Try this Method..

Comment: Possible to do this without using ActionBarSherlock and just stock Android ActionBar?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I've just had exactly the same problem - for me the issue was that I had this:

```
 <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/btn_dark</item>
 <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/btn_dark</item>
```

Where btn_dark was a re-used drawable for generic buttons defining a color for the enabled, pressed and disabled states. It works fine on newer devices but on my old 2.3 phone I was getting a gray background on the title.

Interestingly the disabled state (for which I had set as a dark gray color), was applied on older devices to the background of the action bar title. Setting the disabled color to transparent was the fix.